# What can cause IllegalMonitorStateException in the given sample code

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn java concurrency programming. Kindly check my sample code and help me understanding why I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException" even though I have called wait() and notify in a synchronized context.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.m1();
    }

    private void m1() {
        Example ex = new Example();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ex);
        t1.start();
        synchronized (ex) {
            System.out.println("waiting");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }    
    }

    public class Example implements Runnable {    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running");
            notifyMethod();
        }

        private void notifyMethod() {
            System.out.println("Notifying");
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect out of "waiting,running,notifying" but the actual output is:

```
waiting
Running
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
Notifying
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at examples.Test.m1(Test.java:18)
    at examples.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Its hard to read ("enter your code here" ...).

Answer (score 0):

First of, I think synchonizing on a `Runnable` isn't a good idea (`Example` in your case). You either synchonize on `this` or, even better, on a dedicated `Object`, that is `lock` in my example. **Edit:** Synchronizing on a `Runnable` is the same as using `this` but for me it looks better. Guts tell me there might be something more to that, but I'm not an expert in this field. Dedicated lock `Object` is always better, read [this article](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/object-vs-class-level-locking/) if you want to find out more on the topic.

Then, while synchonizing on a `lock`, you have to call `wait()` on that same object: `lock.wait()`. If you synchronize on `this`, then you call `this.wait()` or just `wait()`.

When you want to notify the waiting thread, you again have to synchronize on the `lock` and call `notify()` on that object: `lock.notify()`. Both the monitor in the synchronize and the object on which you call `notify()` have to be the exact same object you have called `wait()` on.

Here is a code that works:

```
public class Test {
  public static final Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.m1();
    }

    private void m1() {
        Example ex = new Example();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ex);
        t1.start();
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("waiting");
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }    
    }


    public static class Example implements Runnable {    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running");
            notifyMethod();
        }

        private void notifyMethod() {
            System.out.println("Notifying");
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amongalen for the working code. I didn't create new lock object instead I tried calling ex.wait() instead of just wait() and that gave me the expected output. 
Would like to know why you said 'synchonizing on a Runnable isn't a good idea' ?

Comment: @Shridevi added some extra info to that paragraph, check it out.